# How do I run commercial software via scripting that allows for I/O operations?

Tags: python, excel, shell, scripting

My challenge today is that I have some commercial software (random program purchased for engineering applications) and I would like to be able to run it given inputs I have in excel. Now, I know that using the **openpyxl** library I can read, write, and manipulate data I pull from excel so my next question is:

How do I use my python script to open a program, make a several selections and inputs in the program (using data I already have from excel), and record several outputs?

Would I have to look to creating a batch file for this, or some other type of script, also any recommended reading on this would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the commercial software have a CLI? An API of some kind? This is too broad to answer in the general sense, and in the specific sense this isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: The product appears to have a batch mode via the command prompt, I suggest you look at that.  In particular you might be able to feed it data through a pipe.  Did you try asking the support line for the supplier?

Comment: Just sent them an email. Thanks cdarke!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the program? What OS is it running on?

- it may have an explicit API you can use;
- it may make some internals accessible via COM automation (or similar)
- it may have its own scripting language
- you may be able to feed it events (ie keypresses and button clicks)
- it may be command-line callable

Without details it's really hard to say more.

**Edit:** if the program is [StructurePoint's spColumn](https://www.structurepoint.org/soft/soft_genfeat.asp?l_family_id=53) then it has a command-line batch mode (see https://www.structurepoint.org/pdfs/presentation/spColumnPresentation.pdf page 25) which would likely do what you want.

You create a .cti (spColumn Text Input, which specifies the input values) and feed it to the program; I presume it then spits out a text summary of the analysis. The user manual supposedly has "a detailed section designed to help users modify and develop their CTI files for batch mode analysis."

For further info you could try emailing them, info@structurepoint.org

**Edit 2:** [the manual](https://www.structurepoint.org/pdfs/manuals/spColumn%20Manual.pdf) has a section on .cti files, starting on page A3 (pg 101 of the linked .pdf). They suggest the best way to create a .cti file is to use the GUI to set up a model and then Save As (File type: .cti). You can then edit the resulting file (it is just plain-text, but be very careful with respect to unit conversions etc). You can get more information on how to do a batch run from Help -> Command Line Help...

A basic command-line call would look like

```
spcolumn.exe /i:inputfile.cti /o:outfile.csv /csv
```

which saves the results as a .csv file.

Comment: The program is called SPColumn, running on Windows 7 and I am not sure of the language it is written in. Typically engineering softwares such as this one are written in C++, and the documentation is limited but I do not believe it has an API, accessible internals or its own scripting language.

Comment: Without such knowledge how would I know how to feed the program keypresses or program clicks and the relating input options? Also thank you for your response Hugh

Comment: Is this it? https://www.structurepoint.org/soft/software-profile.asp?l_family_id=53  Looks like latest version is 5.00.

Comment: Yes that would be it!

Comment: I will test this out! You sir have been extremely helpful!